# How can I download a git branch without using git command

Tags: git, github, pygithub

I have a private repo and I want to download a branch files from it. My environment doesn't have the git command installed. It would be great if I can do this with Python/PyGithub

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why can't you just install the git command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repo is on github, right ?

Through the GUI : when you view the content of a file, you can see a `Raw` button on the top right part of the file view.

This points you to a url, which will give you the raw content of said file.

Here is an example :

- `Readme.md` of the golang repo can be viewed here :
  https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/README.md
- raw content of same file can be viewed here :
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/go/master/README.md

You simply have to download this file, e.g :

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/go/master/README.md
```

For a file in a private repo, you will need to also pass some credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to download files from the repository ?
if yes you can copy the files to a local destination.

If you want to checkout the new dev branch off of the repository you an use the UI to do that.